# How to access value of select list in html using php

Tags: php, html, post, request, href

```html
<form action="pickup_locations.php" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <!--List Select-->
                    <select class="form-control" size="10" name="locationId" onselect="selectPickupLocation()">
                        <?php
                        $locations = getPickupLocationList();
                        foreach($locations as $location) {
                            echo '<option value="'.$location['id'].'">'.$location['name'].'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            &nbsp;
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                        <!--Create and Edit Buttons-->
                        <p><a href="pickup_location_form.php?action=create" class="btn btn-secondary">Create</a></p>
                        &nbsp;
                        <?php
                        $locationId = $_POST['locationId'];
                        echo '<p><a href="pickup_location_form.php?action=edit&locationId='.$locationId.'" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</a></p>';
                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

The above is my html code I have. This code essentially displays a list that can be selected, followed by 2 buttons, create and edit.

I want these buttons to redirect to another php script, however, if edit is clicked, I need to add the value of the select list into the url. The way I have it now does not work, anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: That will only be there after you first submit the form to PHP. You cannot grab a POST value before its submitted in this way. You would want to use javascript to grab what is in the option value, and attach it to the href, and then redirect the user.

Comment: Does create and edit lead POST to the same script? If they do post to the same script, you can check if the record exist, if it does its an edit if not its a create.

If they do not post to the same script you can use javascript to change the url it is going do on click.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following codes.
You can use the POST data to load the Edit form at pickup_location_form.php
converting the Edit link into submit button and the form's **action="pickup_location_form.php?action=edit"**

```
<form action="pickup_location_form.php?action=edit" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" size="10" name="locationId" onselect="selectPickupLocation()">
                <?php
                $locations = getPickupLocationList();
                foreach($locations as $location) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$location['id'].'">'.$location['name'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
                </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <p><a href="pickup_location_form.php?action=create" class="btn btn-secondary">Create</a></p>
                <p><button class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</button></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

On the pickup_location_form.php file:

```
<?php
//pickup_location_form.php
$action = isset($_GET['action'])? $_GET['action'] : '';
if ($action == 'create') {
    // ... Load the Edit form here ...
}
else if (($action == 'edit') && !empty($_POST['locationId'])) {
    $locationId = $_POST['locationId'];
    // ... Load the Edit form here for the $locationId ...
}
else {
    // Neither Create or Edit was selected, you redirect to the previous page here or do something else....
}
?>
```